# A question on the $2$-torsion points of a elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am reading Saito's *Fermat's Last Theorem: Basic tools* and on page 15, it was claimed that

> Proposition 1.4. Let $K$ be a field with char($K$) $\neq 2$, and let E be an elliptic curve over $K$. Then all $2$-torsion points of $E$ are $K$ rational if and only if there exist distinct nonzero elements $n$ and $m$ in $K$ such that $E$ is isomorphic to the elliptic curve defined by $$y^2 = x(x-n)(x-m)$$

> Proof. Suppose $E$ is defined by $y^2=f(x)$. Let $L$ be an extension of $K$. We prove that a point $P=(s,t)\neq O$ in $E(L)$ is of order $2$ if and only if the $f(s)=t=0$. By the definition of the group law, $P$ is of order $2$ iff the tangent line at $P$ passes through $O=(0:1:0)$. Since a line in $\mathbf P^2$ passesthrough $O$ iff it is parallel to the $y$-axis, the tangent line must be the line $x=s$. This is equivalent to the fact that the system of eqeuation $x=s, y^2 = f(x)$ has a multiple root at $(x,y)= (s,t)$.

> This, in turn, is equivalent to $f(s) =t=0$.

Then the author claimed that

> Thus, all the $2$-torsion are $K$-rational if and only if $f(x)$ is decomposed into linear factors over $K$.

Does the author somehow assume there are at least $3$ distinct $2$-torsion points on $E$, which are all $K$-rational?

**EDIT**: I somehow get that I need to use the definition of elliptic curves where $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, and by definition has no multiple roots. The problem is solved now.

Comment: Can you add more details to question? I'm struggling to understand it without actually having the book in front of me

Comment: Over $\overline K$, there are exactly $3$ distinct points of order $2$. (You can see this, for example, by using the fact that, over $\mathbb C$,  $E(\mathbb C) \cong \mathbb C/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$.) If you write your curve in the form $y^2 = f(x)$, the non-trivial $2$-torsion points are exactly the points $(\alpha, 0) - \infty$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$. So a $2$-torsion point is defined over $K$ if and only if $\alpha\in K$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: For an elliptic curve in the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ then in the group law $-(x,y)=(x,-y)$ so $(x,y)+(x,y)=O$ iff $y=0$ or $y=\infty$.